# I get this error when deploying a new data model in aws amplify

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

In all my app's backends when I try to deploy a new data model I get this error in AWS Amplify `Unknown directive "key"..`

I recently updated the amplify cli to the latest version and only after that I'm getting these errors. I'm very new to programming.

**Screenshot of error:**

[image: the error]

Answer (score 0):

that is because, Amplify has updated its GraphQL Transforme to V2 from V1.

to update your models you have to migrate your api to the new version.

```
amplify migrate api
```

Then you can push to backend using

```
amplify push api
```

For more information: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/migration/transformer-migration/